# Translate MongoDB Aggregation $all (JS) into Doctrine ODM Aggregation (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I am currently trying to convert this JS code:

```
db.Issue.aggregate( [
  { // Filter out issues that have been worked on after our given week = All worklogs muste have been before date
      $match : { 
          worklogs: { $all: [
            { 
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    date: { $lte: endDate }
                }    
            },
          ] }
      }
  }
] )
```

(Based on official documentation: [Use $all with $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch)

Into Doctrine ODM code using their aggregation builder:

```
$builder = $this->createAggregationBuilder();

$aggregation = $builder
    ->match()
        ->field('worklogs')
        ->all([
            $builder->matchExpr()->elemMatch(
               $builder->expr()->field('date')->lte($week->getEndDate())
               )
       ])
;
```

However, apparently I am unable to match the `$all` correctly - meaning in a way that allows me to ensure that **all entries** in a collection fulfilled the requirements checked by `$elemMatch`.

The original MongoDB query in JS seems to do the trick, but I cannot manage to receive the same results in PHP. By now I am not even sure Doctrine can handle that combination of `$all` and `$elemMatch`.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your comments so far! I am however still struggling with the current query syntax (in PHP!) for the `$not` / `->not()` operator. I have already checked the docs here: [Doctrine ODM Docs](http://doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest) but could not find anything useful. (Please also note, that I am using version 2.0 here).

Right now my query looks like:

```
->match()
    ->field('worklogs')
        ->not([
            $builder->matchExpr()->elemMatch(
                $builder->matchExpr()->field('date')->gt($week->getEndDate())
            )
        ])
```

But leads to this error:

> 1) App\Tests\Repository\IssueRepositoryTest::testGetEstimationsPerWeek
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: $not needs a regex or a document
>   /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php:263
>   /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php:223
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Aggregation/Builder.php:168
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Aggregation/Stage.php:35
>   /var/www/html/src/Repository/IssueRepository.php:85

Comment: Just a PHP Translation error. That's actually `->all([ [$builder->.... ] ])`, noting the additional `[]`. Just the *singular* `[]` ( as you have ) means `{}` in translation, So you want `[ { ... } ]` and therefore the additional `[]` or `array()` in older speak.

Comment: You don't need neither $all nor $elemMatch in this particular case. `{$match: {"worklogs.date": {$lte: endDate}}}` does exactly the same.

Comment: @AlexBlex would that not also match results where only ONE entry in the collection fulfils the requirements ? Whereas I want a query that matches ALL elements ?

Comment: You have only 1 $elemMatch in the array, so it is ALL of 1 element. I think you misunderstand what $all does. If you already read the page behind the link you posted in the question, scroll to the top and re-read again paying attention to each word. Also "collection" in mongodb is used to refer to a collection of documents - in your case "Issue" is a collection. "worklogs" is not a collection but an array of documents, subdocuments, or embedded documents. Please stick to terminology to avoid confusion.

Comment: Neither form actually returns where **ALL elements** in the array match the condition. If that's what you wanted you would in fact **reverse** the condition to `$gt` and use `$not`. i.e `"worklogs": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "date": { "$gt": endDate } } } }`. The `$all` example you point to in the documentation actually applies as "multiple conditions", and not "ALL array elements" as you have presumed.

Comment: Thank you all, that was already really helpful. I am however still struggling with the current query syntax (in PHP!) for the `$not` / `->not()` operator. I have already checked the docs here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/ but could not find anything useful. (Please also note, that I am using version 2.0 here).

Comment: Right now my query looks like:

```
            ->match()
                ->field('worklogs')
                ->not([
                    $builder->matchExpr()->elemMatch(
                        $builder->matchExpr()->field('date')->gt($week->getEndDate())
                    )
                ])
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the help of @neil-lunn, I was able to figure out the correct query:

```
->match()
    ->field('worklogs')
        ->not(
            $builder->matchExpr()->elemMatch(
                $builder->matchExpr()->field('date')->gt($week->getEndDate())
            )
        )
```